# "Filtering" DataTable using Row Filter

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, rowfilter

I have a `DataTable` dt. 
I want to filter data of table dt using row filter. my query have some sql pre-defined  function like - `REPLACE`,`CHARINDEX`,`SUBSTRING`. but when applying row filter on `DataTable` some problem occurred.

After googling i found this post `http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/` , i think sql function (REPLACE, CHARINDEX) not supported by row filter but in sql server it's working good. 
How can i do this using row filter or any other method for filtering data into `DataTable`

MY query -

```
SELECT *
FROM TblUsers
WHERE REPLACE(substring(COLUMN-NAME,0,charindex(';',COLUMN-NAME)),'REPLACE-KEYWORD','REPLACE WITH') like 'name ie8'
```

Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to simplify your query a little bit, as the DataTable row filtering does not support many of the functions available in SQL. [Take a look at this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for a detailed description of the syntax, functions and operators you can use.